# Nodejs any file system provider

Tags: node.js, io

Is there any library for nodejs, which are supporting different types of storage, like FTP, AmazonS3, Google storage, file system. And transparent in usage by code?

For example, it only has an interface of list, read, write file, and separate factory is creating provider based on settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like [pkgcloud](https://github.com/nodejitsu/pkgcloud)? It's a module that abstracts away differences among multiple cloud providers. For [storage](https://github.com/nodejitsu/pkgcloud#storage) it currently supports

- Azure
- Rackspace
- Amazon

No matter which service you are using the module uses `container` and `file`. It is written by the guys from [nodejitsu](http://nodejitsu.com/) and I'm sure they'll add more services (e.g. Google storage) in the future. Or add your own and make a pull request.

Comment: yep, this is not bad solution. but still supports only remote connections, not to local file system.